# Necropolitan sub-type?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead

In the creation paragraph of the Necropolitan (Liber Mortis ~p112) is said that a creature acquiring this template gain the undead type and *atypical* sub-type (The subtype may have another name but I don't know for sure since my handbook is not in english).
Can someone point me to where i can found the stat block of the *atypical* Subtype, or at least tell me the exact english translation for the sub-type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to remember the Necropolitan template adds the [Augmented Subtype](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#augmentedSubtype) which does not seem to have any benefits (or penalties) and is added to the list of subtypes.

Comment: Augmented is basically used to “track” type changes.

Comment: interesting, it seams to be a bad translation then. Thank you !